# Inconsistent UTC offset when converting local time to UTC in same versions compiled with different Android SDKs

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sdk, timezone-offset

I am encountering an issue with the UTC offset when converting local time to UTC in same versions of my Unity application for Android. I have two versions of my application running on the same device. The first version is compiled using SDK 33, while the second version is compiled using SDK 30.

The purpose of the code is to convert local time to UTC in order to schedule notifications. However, I have noticed that the first version is returning an incorrect UTC offset of +1. The device is currently configured to Spain's daylight saving time, which should have a UTC offset of +2. Surprisingly, the second version of the application returns the correct UTC offset of +2.

I have examined the code responsible for the conversion, and it is the same in both versions. I have also verified that the device's time zone settings are correct. Strangely, I haven't come across any similar complaints or known issues related to this problem. Could this be an error caused by the SDK, or is there something else I should consider?

This is my code:

```
private void saveNotification(DateTime selected_day, Serializables.Shedule_data[] shedule_data) {
...
                        TimeSpan tspan = TimeSpan.Parse(shedule_data[i].inicio);
                        DateTime localTime = new DateTime(selected_day.Year, selected_day.Month, selected_day.Day, tspan.Hours, tspan.Minutes, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
                        DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localTime);
                        LogManager.Instance.log($"Saved notification at -> Local({TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now)}): {localTime:dd/MM/yyy - HH:mm} | {TimeZoneInfo.Utc.DisplayName}: {utcTime:dd/MM/yyy - HH:mm}");
```

To troubleshoot the issue, I tried the following steps:

Checked the device's time zone settings: I verified that the device is correctly set to Spain's daylight saving time, which should have a UTC offset of +2.

Reviewed the conversion code: I carefully inspected the code responsible for converting local time to UTC in both versions of the application. There are no apparent differences, and both versions use the same logic for the conversion.

Tested the second version: To ensure it was not an environmental issue, I specifically tested the second version of the application. It consistently returns the expected UTC offset of +2.

Considering that the code is the same in both versions and the device's time zone settings are correct, I expected both versions to return the same UTC offset of +2. However, the first version continues to produce an incorrect offset of +1.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to further investigate and resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: This may be related to the bug I reported: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/datetimenow-reports-the-wrong-date-on-mobile-devices-when-having-a-specific-time-zone - They have a fix that should be coming soon